# How to get the response (conten) of a specific item in a Google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm processing the result of a Google form with GAS. I can obtain the responses (= answers) of all items (= form questions) by:

```
let rbForm = FormApp.openById("nmkhVb56R…");
let rbFormResponses = rbForm.getResponses()[rbForm.getResponses().length - 1];
let rbItemResponses = rbFormResponses.getItemResponses();

Logger.log(rbItemResponses[0].getResponse()); // The answer of the first question
```

But now I need to have the response to a specific item and I need to address this item by its itemId. How can I get this object directly without iterating through all responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Form.getItemById()` and `FormResponse.getResponseForItem().getResponse()`, like this:

```js
function test() {
  const rbForm = FormApp.openById('nmkhVb56R…');
  const item = rbForm.getItemById('...');
  const responses = rbForm.getResponses();
  const lastResponse = responses[responses.length - 1];
  const answer = lastResponse.getResponseForItem(item).getResponse();
  console.log(answer);
}
```